# gmail account recovery with android phone

Tags: gmail

Say I have attached my android phone to a gmail account and specify that phone for account recovery.

If I am locked out of the gmail account, will I be able to operate the phone sufficiently to receive the confirmation signal from google, even though its link to google is severed?

Comment: Yes; But setup all other recovery options

Comment: Yes; you should have a recovery email for the gmail account, a phone number, SMS, ect. you should backup the google authenticator so it can be restored to any device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not if you're using the google authenticator app. You will be able to receive the sms with the code, but you won't be able to link the app. Always print out your backup codes in case of this:

Account - Security - 2 step verification - backup codes

[image]